# How do I properly make a class internal?

Tags: c#, internal

Just a quick question: I want only one class of my assembly to be public and everything else invisible to the outside. Do I just set all other classes with their methods and properties to internal? Is this even a good approach?

Comment: "Is this even a good approach?"  Well there's nothing _inherently_ wrong with it, but you don't give much context to know if it's the right approach.

Comment: As @Christos metionned, the default acces modifier of the class  is internal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All classes by default are `internal`. So if you want them to be `public` you have to state this.

So you can make the single class you want to be public as public and mark the rest of them as `internal`, since that enhance the readability of your code, as *Silvermind* has pointed out in his comment.

When a class is `internal` it can be accessed only by types in the same assembly. That being said, you have to decide if the methods of a type, which is internal are going to be used by other types inside the same assembly or not. If a method will not be called by another type, then you have to declare it as a `private`, otherwise as a `public`. The same holds for the properties. Furthermore a class member can also be `protected`. For more inofrmation on the latter, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx).

Comment: Just a note, but explicitly marking a class as internal is a better approach than specifying nothing to imply the default behaviour. IMO it is more clear to a programmer what the actual intention was.

Answer (score 1):

By default all classes are `Internal`. So you no need to set classes to internal explicitly.